# TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function in React Native application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I suddenly got this error. My React Native application was working on the browser, I added a couple of lines of code and everything crashed. I have tried everything, including removing the code that had been changed without any result. I've looked for this error on Stackoverflow and other sources and the info I get doesn't help at all. Could someone tell me what might have caused this!

Edit 1:
I wasn't able to find a way around the error so I just rolled back to a recent (git) commit and everything is fine now. I also tried creating a new React Native project with Expo CLI and pasted the old code (the one with the error) and it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you post the code where the problem is?

Comment: I didn't post the code because is a long project. I didn't make changes on a specific piece of code, it just broke. I searched around and found people saying it had something to do with the version of Nodejs I had installed. I tried a different one and it didn't work either. Luckily, I remembered I had a recent git commit and I was able to roll back to it. I rewrote the few (very few) lines I had added since then and everything is working just fine. I guess I'll never know what the problem was. Thanks anyway for taking the time to comment.